# Write audio file to folder python in android studio

Tags: java, android, record

I want to record and save audio 3gp to app/src/main/python folder to use this file to process with python code. But when I save the file with the above path, there is no such file in the python directory. What should I do?

[My picture with this folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSl9K.png)

Here is my code record 3gp file

```
    String path = "app/src/main/python/myrecording.3gp";
    MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setMaxDuration(1000);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setOutputFile(path);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to create the file first in order to save to it. I know it sounds weird because some IDE's for some reason circumvent this, and Android Studio does not (appearantly) , but I've noticed on my device too that it often doesn't do it automatically when I export an application.

Information on the method can be found here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()

If that doesn't help, then please also provide the error the application is giving you in full. The stacktrace is often full of valuable information pertaining to the error that has occured.

Comment: no, it gives no error, i can save and find files in emulator with getExternalFilesDir(), but i can't save to python folder.

Comment: Can you provide the piece of code where the Path is used to specify where the file should be saved? I'm guessing it's not saving it where you expect it. (For example it's saving it directly in the 'App' folder, as I do not see where the path is specified in the above code.

Comment: Sorry I'm new at android. i thought path was `src/python/` because i use  `python.srcDir "src/main/python"` in gradle file? When I use the path as `getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()+"/myrecording.mp3"` the file is saved to the path android/data/com.example.testaudio/files in emulator. You can see in this pisture [link](https://photos.google.com/search/_tra_/photo/AF1QipNk00x2szAXPYB0lw_FszzQp59nDMucVPMZK4hz)

Comment: No problem, it's a learning process. Mistakes happen but practice makes perfect. Also the above link doesn't work (I think the file isn't shared).